# bastille cannot find Curses.pm

Tags: centos, perl, curses

i am running centos 6 and installed the rpm version of bastille, it cannot find Curses.pm, however perl-Curses is installed and somehow even perl cannot find it.

```
[root@server ~]# /usr/sbin/bastille -c
ERROR:   Couldn't determine Red Hat version! Setting to 9!
ERROR:   Couldn't determine Red Hat version! Setting to 9!
NOTE:    Using Curses user interface module.
NOTE:    Only displaying questions relevant to the current configuration.
ERROR:   Could not load the 'Curses.pm' interface module.This may be due to an
         invalid $DISPLAY setting,or the module not being visible to Perl.

[root@server ~]# rpm -qa | grep Curses
perl-Curses-1.28-1.el5.rf.x86_64


[root@server ~]# perl
use Curses;
Can't locate Curses.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at - line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at - line 1.
```

any ideas where i should look further...

[After research]:

i installed 
perl-Curses-1.28-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

and that worked now bastille is complaining about

```
/usr/sbin/bastille -c
ERROR:   Couldn't determine Red Hat version! Setting to 9!
ERROR:   Couldn't determine Red Hat version! Setting to 9!
NOTE:    Using Curses user interface module.
NOTE:    Only displaying questions relevant to the current configuration.
Can't locate Bastille/API/HPSpecific.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/ /usr/lib/Bastille /opt/sec_mgmt/bastille/lib /opt/sec_mgmt/bastille/lib/API /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.6.0/i386-linux /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at /usr/lib/Bastille/IOLoader.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/Bastille/IOLoader.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/sbin/InteractiveBastille line 414.
```

Comment: What is the output of `updatedb && locate Curses.pm`?

Answer (score 1):

Google is your and mine friend. Found this entry at http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2767305&group_id=403&atid=100403

> Did a lot of Googling and testing; my conclusion is that the current
>   version (3.2.1 - September 25, 2008 - Bastille-3.2.1-0.1.noarch.rpm)
>   is not working except perhaps for one ore more specific distros
>   (64-bit, HP only?). The project's news page
>   (http://bastille-linux.sourceforge.net/news_updates.htm) last item is
>   "September 12, 2007: There's a release coming tomorrow - stay tuned."
>   I'm guessing Jay isn't around anymore and the HP sponsored team has
>   been focused on their platform rather than maintaining the package as
>   an open solution. The fact that the (apparently working) older version
>   (Bastille-3.0.9-1.0.noarch.rpm) isn't (easily?) available here doesn't
>   help. Here are the steps I've followed on CentOS 5:
>
> downloaded from here and installed 3.2.1-0.1 via rpm -ivh yum install
>   perl-Curses
>
> bastille -c
>
> Error message: Can't locate Bastille/API.pm in @INC . . .
>
> grep'd /usr/sbin/InteractiveBastille for "use lib" line found Bastille
>   directory (containing API.pm) in /usr/lib64 rather than /usr/lib, so
>   moved it to /usr/lib (also could have symlinked or edited the IB
>   script)
>
> Then got: Can't locate Bastille/API/HPSpecific.pm
>
> Turns out (as noted below) both the rpm and the source package lack an
>   'API' folder.
>
> Created the folder and used wget to retrieve the files from the SCM
>   repository:
>   http://bastille-linux.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bastille-linux/dev/working_tree/Bastille/Bastille/API/
>
> Then got "Could not determine CentOS version". Someone had claimed the
>   below would work, but it didn't:
>
> Changed /etc/redhat-release from CentOS release 5 (Final) to: Red Hat
>   Enterprise Linux Server release 5 (Tikanga)
>
> Further errors coming from the new scripts in the API directory, so
>   gave up. Will now try the older version, available via direct download
>   here:
>
> http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/bastille-linux/Bastille-3.0.9-1.0.noarch.rpm
>
> IMO this is no way to run a railroad, but since I'm just an end-user
>   and not a contributor I guess I've got no right to B&M about it. While
>   I'm at it thanks to all the developers who've put in so much of their
>   time and energy on this tool, just looking at the code is a good
>   learning experience so far. Here's hoping it gets some love in the
>   future to bring it in sync with current distro versions. . .
>
> And I hope this post saves others from wasting some of their time -
>   feedback welcome.

Comment: thanks mailq, will check out tomorrow, i might switch to debian..